# How to calculate the probability that there is at least one math student in each group

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

Given 18 students, 12 math students and 6 CS students, we want to split all 18 into 3 groups. I am trying to find the probability that each group contains at least one math student.

There are ${18 \choose 6}$ ways to arrange 6 students. The probability that there is at least one math student in a group is P(M)=1-P(C) where P(C) is the probability of the whole group being only CS students.

$1-\frac{1}{{18 \choose 6}}=\frac{18563}{18564}$ is the probability of a group containing at least one math student.

I am not sure where to go here

Comment: What there are ${18}\choose{6}$ of is 6-student subsets of your 18-student universe. Arranging nearly always involves permutations, which get counted using factorials, not binomial coefficients.

Comment: If you’re partitioning the 18 students into three 6-student parts, there are ${18 \choose 6}{12 \choose 6} / 3!$ ways to do that.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum ${18 \choose 6}$ means you choose 6 students from a group of 18. ${12 \choose 6}$ is the remaining 6 for the next group and 6 choose 6 is just 1. But why divide by 3! if the order of the group doesnt matter?

Comment: You divide by $3!$ **because** the order of the groups doesn’t matter.

Answer (score 1):

Line up 18 placemats in 3 groups of 6 each.  Count ways to select places among them for the 6 CS students.  Don't worry about which student goes where, just about where to place CS students.

There are $\binom{18}6$ distinct equiprobable ways to select any 6 among a line of 18 *placemats*.

There are **3** ways to select one of the three groups of 6 placemats.

If you do *not* put all the CS students in the same group, then there will be at least one math student in each group.

So, there are $\binom{18}6-3$ ways to select 6 placemats so that we have a favoured placement of CS students.

Divide and calculate.